# Error with M1 Native Installation of MySQL with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I just got my first MacOS system with an M1 chip and I'm having trouble installing the native M1 version of MySQL using Homebrew. I have my terminal configured without Rosetta and I'm using the command "brew install MySQL" but I get this error:

```
ritvikbiswas@Ritviks-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install mysql
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
ritvikbiswas@Ritviks-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Could anyone help me figure out why I'm getting this error? Maybe I messed up the brew installation somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed Homebrew into the wrong place. On x86 Mac, Homebrew uses `/usr/local`. On M1 Mac, Homebrew uses `/opt/homebrew`. I don't know where you copied and pasted the installation script. You obviously made a wrong installation.

Please go the official [installation guide page](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). And

1. Uninstall your current homebrew
2. Reinstall homebrew back correctly following the guide.

Comment: This worked for me! I made such a silly mistake to not follow the last two on-screen instructions for the native M1 install. I made sure that this time over my native install was in the /opt folder and the Rosetta in /usr/local! Success here! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

First, **uninstall** (if you have wrongly installed it).

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

**Install**:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**After successful installation, you can get this message in terminal**

- Run these three commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:

> ```
> echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/userName/.zprofile
> echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/userName/.zprofile
> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> ```

**Then set the homebrew to the right path**

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution to the problem. Great help!